# How can I play Unturned offline?

Tags: unturned

Sometimes I'll be somewhere where I have no internet whatsoever.

Trying to play Unturned yields the following message, regardless of whether or not Steam is in Online or Offline mode:

[image]

It always says "Sorry: Steam Not Found"

I've searched on the forums, and it looks like others have had this problem as well.

How can I play Unturned offline?

Comment: There are binary patches (aka 'cracks') which might be legal in your country of residence.

Comment: @Annan cracks are NEVER the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done it with a laptop. I launch Unturned in a place with Internet and leave it running, it will still run when the connection is lost. Though this technique can be a bit inconvenient, it is the only one I know of that works.